# Definir classe para uma tabela

Tags: python, flask

Estou começando agora com [`Flask`](http://flask.pocoo.org) e me deparei com a seguinte dúvida: como faço para definir uma classe da tabela utilizando o [`flask_table`](https://github.com/plumdog/flask_table)?

Segue meu código de exemplo e o resultado:

```
from flask_table import Table, Col

class TabelaDados(Table):
    codigo = Col('Código')
    nome = Col('Nome')
    ip = Col('Ip')

@app.route('/dados')
def dados():
    dados_pc = TI.query.all()
    table = TabelaDados(dados_pc)
    print(table.__html__())
    return render_template('dados.html', tabela=table)
```

Está retornando a tabela corretamente, mas queria incluir uma classe [css](/questions/tagged/css) para a tabela.

Comment: Está a tentar implementar um ORM? Se estiver a tentar aconselho a ler mais sobre sqlalchemy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No repositório do projeto tem uma pasta de exemplos. [Aqui](https://github.com/plumdog/flask_table/blob/master/examples/classes.py#L25) tem um exemplo de como referenciar classes na tabela.

```
class TabelaDados(Table):

    classes = ['tabela-fixa', 'tabela-pequena']

    codigo = Col('Código')
    nome = Col('Nome')
    ip = Col('Ip')
```

Só atente para o caso da palavra `classes` ser usada como referencia para atribuir classes CSS. Não use ela como nome de campo do model.